# select sub-children of div of specific type

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select all the "input"-children of the "div"-children of my "mainDiv". I tried it with 'div input:first-child' as you can see below and as I found it on http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/. But it doesn't work. If I use only 'div' as filter it works fine. So what is my mistake? Or how to get to all the "input"-children in an easy way?

```
        var data = ['name1', 'name2'];
        var mainDiv = $('<div>');
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            var div = $('<div>').appendTo(mainDiv);
            $('<input type="checkbox">').appendTo(div);
            div.append(' ' + data[i]);
        }
        mainDiv.children('div input:first-child').each(
            function()
            {
                var child = $(this);
                alert('xx');
            });
```

Comment: cant understand why more than 3k views and not even one vote up for your question. get mine!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you are trying to get all of the `input` elements that are children of a `div`:

```
mainDiv.find("div > input");
```

If you want all descendant `input` elements, not only direct children:

```
mainDiv.find("div input");
```

Note that you need to use `find`, not `children`. The `children` method only looks at direct children, and returns them if they match the selector. The selector `div input` will not match any of the direct children (the only direct child is a `div`) so no elements are returned.

Comment: no, I want to get all of the input elements that are children of div elements which are children of a specific div, namend 'mainDiv' in my source

Comment: @user1027167 - Yes, you will need to use `find`. I've added a little explanation of why that is the case.

Comment: @user1027167 children() only returns the first level below, similar to the css `>` selector. children('div').children('input') would have worked. But as you found out, find() would be the best way in this case. Edit: Didnt notice James explanation, oh well :)

Comment: @Johan - No harm in having two explanations! I think yours is slightly clearer, I was struggling to explain it in clear terms!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are actually creating a div with

```
 var mainDiv = $('<div>');
```

then you append a `<div>` to it

```
 var div = $('<div>').appendTo(mainDiv);
```

Then you append a `<input>` to the `<div>`

```
 $('<input type="checkbox">').appendTo(div);
```

So the input are not direct children of mainDiv , they are descendant so you have to do

```
 mainDiv.find('input').each
```